# Random shuffle and function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following function, which generates an integer in a given range:

```
 18 int choosecard(){
 19     boost::uniform_int<> dist(0,51);
 20     boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > cardchoice(gen, dist);
 21     return cardchoice();
 22 }
```

I want to use it as an argument to std::random_shuffle, so that I can shuffle a vector of 52 integers.

```
 64     int (*pchoosecard)(void) = choosecard;
 65 
 66     std::random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), pchoosecard);
```

However I get this error that I don't understand:

```
$ make
g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_45_0/ -c main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_45_0/boost/any.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_45_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_45_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_45_0/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::random_shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Generator&) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Generator = int (*)()]’:
main.cpp:66:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:4998: error: too many arguments to function
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Everything compiles fine when I comment out the line that calls std::random_shuffle.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "too many arguments" because `std::random_shuffle` is trying to pass too many arguments to the callback that you gave it. So it's really too **few** parameters.

Your `choosecard` is supposed to accept one parameter, of type `ptrdiff_t`, which tells the function the number of elements, basically. (You are not supposed to hardcode the number of cards in this function.) So you plug that in to the `boost::uniform_dist` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still quite confused. I don't have a uniform_dist constructor. Do you mean the line with boost::uniform_int<> dist(0,51)? I've made choosecard take a ptrdiff_t, i. And then changed the aforementioned line to boost::uniform_int<> dist(0,i-1);

However I'm just getting more cryptic bugs

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class RandomNumberGenerator>
void random_shuffle ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                      RandomNumberGenerator& rand );
```

> **first, last**
>
> Forward iterators to the initial and final
>    positions of the sequence to
>   be shuffled. The range used is
>   [first,last), which contains all the
>   elements between first and last,
>   including the element pointed by first
>   but not the element pointed by last.
>
> **rand**
>
> Pointer to unary function **taking one argument** and returning a value,
>   both of the appropriate difference
>   type (generally ptrdiff_t). The
>   function shall return a value between
>   zero and its argument (lower than
>   this).