# use boost instead of random_r/srandom_r?

Tags: boost, random, bind

I'm trying to maintain separate random seeds for different clients (from server app).
random_r/srandom_r(linux api) can't be used because the code must compile both on mac/linux.

It seems I could use boost::random instead of random_r/srandom_r.

I've tried defining my random function(which is class member function) and supply the function to random_shuffle's 3rd parameter.

```
random_shuffle( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                        RandomNumberGenerator& rand );


ptrdiff_t MyClass::_MyRandom(ptrdiff_t i)
{
    int result;

    boost::uniform_int<> numberInterval( 1, 10000);
    boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >
        dice(mRng, numberInterval); // mRng is boost::mt19937 type instance variable

    result = dice();
    //  random_r(mRandomData, &result);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    result = result % i;

    return result;
}
```

what's the proper form of bind() here?

```
mRng.seed(mRandomSeed); //mRandomSeed will be different for different clients.
//I'm trying to random_shuffle a vector with the random seed.
random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&MyClass::_MyRandom, _1));
```

Being not so familiar with boost::random boost::bind, i'm not so sure if my approach is going to work.
Any comment on direction would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some code that does what you want [here](http://snipplr.com/view/5907/stdrandomshuffle-and-boostrandomhpp/). 
[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352346/random-shuffle-and-function-pointers) has simpler code, but uses a function pointer instead of a function object, which will not be as efficient.  Here is some (not tested) code to try as the last argument to `random_shuffle`:

```
template <typename Gen>
struct shuffle_wrapper {
  Gen& gen;
  shuffle_wrapper(Gen& gen): gen(gen) {}
  int operator()(int r) const {return boost::uniform_int<>()(gen, r);}
};

shuffle_wrapper<`your generator type`>(`your generator`)
```

Comment: I've successfully used the code given in the first link(which has Random class). Just one little bump was that I won't know the size of vector until later and I wanted to have Random as member variable. I defined default Random() constructor, and later reassigned it as mRandomInstance = Random(vector.size()); also, I have code of copying mRandomInstance = rhs.mRandomInstance in class which has mRandomInstance as a variable. Are both practices fine?

Comment: @Eugene: Note that the code I posted doesn't use the vector size anywhere.  The range of random numbers is chosen by `random_shuffle`, and probably changes during the algorithm (the typical algorithm for shuffling does that).

Comment: oh I thought, 10 in Random rnd(10) is the size of vector. doesn't have to be?, actually my constructor takes(N, randomSeed), and even though I don't need to pass vector size to constructor, the above question still remains. is reassigning,copying the Random class fine?

Comment: @Eugene: Oh, you're looking at one of the other code variants, not the `boost::bind` version.  That code is probably wrong, then.  Could you please try the one I posted and see if that works for you?

Comment: @Eugene: I'd be interested to see if it works for you, though, since people will think that's the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: @Jeremiah: I've posted your bind approach code at http://codepad.org/RKJXjRLl  with compile error message.

Comment: @Eugene: Replace `boost::ref(&Test15Class::_MyRandom)` by `boost::ref(mRng)`; the `<your generator>` part is meant to be the Boost generator object.

Comment: @Eugene: I gave up on `boost::bind`; I just put in a function object, which should be faster anyway.  See the edited version.